# how to stop loading animation once the screen is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Play:400,700);
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #222;
  font-family: "Play";
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.smart-glass {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 288px;
  height: 388px;
}

.logo {
  width: 288px;
  height: 288px;
  position: relative;
}

.circle {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #40A800;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: connect 2.5s linear infinite;
}

.xbox {
  background: #FFF;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.xbox:after, .xbox:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-top: 10px solid #222;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 90%;
  width: 120%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  position: absolute;
  right: -30%;
  top: 15%;
}
.xbox:before {
  left: -30%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.loading-text {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

@keyframes connect {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="smart-glass">
  <h1>Xbox</h1>
  <div class="logo">
    <div class="circle">
      <div class="circle">
          <div class="circle">
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hold-x">
    <div class="xbox"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="loading-text">
    Loading...
  </div>
</div>
```

Well i saw this loading animation on one website and i am planning to insert it into my code but the problem i am having is that how do i stop the animation once the page has completed loading. Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: just hide he element which holds the loader.

Comment: can you answer with the code because i am a beginner and i am not able to understand how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first `fadeOut` the animated part and then `remove`the DOM content of it

```
 $(".smart-glass").fadeOut(3000,function(){  // Will fade out in 3 secs
  $(".smart-glass").remove();   // animated part will be removed from DOM
  $('body').css('background-color',"#fff"); // background will be changed to white
 })
})
```

[PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/bWjVPf1fwHUEqMuDVdUm?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You can do like:

```
$('.smart-glass').css('display','none');
```

Here i set interval to hide. Which hide after some times. You can use above code when you like to hide the animation.

```js
setInterval(function(){ $('.smart-glass').fadeOut(); 
$('body').css('background', 'transparent');

 }, 5000);
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Play:400,700);
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #222;
  font-family: "Play";
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.smart-glass {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 288px;
  height: 388px;
}

.logo {
  width: 288px;
  height: 288px;
  position: relative;
}

.circle {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #40A800;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: connect 2.5s linear infinite;
}

.xbox {
  background: #FFF;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.xbox:after, .xbox:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-top: 10px solid #222;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 90%;
  width: 120%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  position: absolute;
  right: -30%;
  top: 15%;
}
.xbox:before {
  left: -30%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.loading-text {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

@keyframes connect {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="smart-glass">
  <h1>Xbox</h1>
  <div class="logo">
    <div class="circle">
      <div class="circle">
          <div class="circle">
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hold-x">
    <div class="xbox"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="loading-text">
    Loading...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @ketan it is working! :) but can i fade out the animation once it is completed and also how do i remove the black background after the page has loaded

Comment: @Samhawkz I have edited the answer. Because background color is for body you can remove like given in JQuery. Or You can add  background color to `smart-glass` div. So, no need to remove background separately .

Comment: Thank you so much @ketan you are the best! :D

Answer (score 1):

Why not using an if statement for this purpose? It seems to fit this scenario perfectly. I was looking for the same thing and could not find anything easy and really works, so I simply put the loader inside the if statement as below. Works for my PHP code.

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['something'])) {
    ?>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div class='loader'></div>
            <br>
            <div> Redirecting...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    echo '<meta http-equiv=REFRESH CONTENT=3;url=url>';
} else {
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the animation to stop on the load of the page, use this JQuery code:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $('.smart-glass').fadeOut(3000);
});
```

This is a JQuery function that makes the opacity go from `1` to `0`, and then `display: none` in 3 seconds (3000 milliseconds). Therefore, after it reaches `display: none`, you can't see it, and the page goes on as normal. You can use inputs, and forms as well, and it won't be affected.

I hope this helps much.

Comment: (can't tag you for some weird reason) anyway. Asked this question 4 years ago hahaha now I'm a full stack (MERN) developer but thanks for the answer sure did bring back some memories :) . I don't even use this stackOverflow account anymore xD